# More stable/efficient cartesian product function to determine all combinations n in length

Tags: python, cartesian-product, dna-sequence

I am working on an error correction method for DNA data storage. It works by identifying errors and then rapidly substituting all possible combinations of bases into error positions until the data decodes. My code correctly identifies errors and substitutes them using an itertools.product loop with one iterable repeated until n in length, n being the number of errors.

```
for error in itertools.product(' ATGC', repeat=len(errorPos)):
    pos = 0
    for base in error:
        if base == " ":
            fseqL[errorPos[pos]] = ""
        else:
            fseqL[errorPos[pos]] = base
        pos = pos + 1
    ffseq = ""
    ffseq = ffseq.join(fseqL)
    try:
        Decoder.dna2binary(ffseq)
    except:
        pLeft = pLeft - 1 
        print("Incorrect decode: %s possibilities left"%(pLeft))
    else:
        print("Data decoded")
        now = datetime.now()
        start = open('data\\log.txt', 'r+')
        end = start.read()
        start.write("\nend: "+str(now))
        start.close()
        break
```

This program works well with small amounts of error, but it exponentially increases in processing time as error increases. The speed isn't a problem, but after about 10-15 errors it becomes unstable and locks up. Is there a better way to find this combination (NumPy function, wrong method, etc.)?

Comment: It seems to me this question is more suited to be asked in the  [Code Review Forum](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  Code Review is a question and answer site for peer programmer code reviews. Please read the relevant guidance related to how to properly ask questions on this site before posting your question.

Comment: @itprorh66 This question appears to be off-topic on Code Review as it contains broken code.